# How did Mother Gothel know (or work out) the 'Flower Song'?

Tags: disney, tangled

How does Mother Gothel know the lyrics and melody to the magical songs that makes the flower (and later Rapunzel's hair) do the rejuvenation and healing magic that we see in Disney's Tangled?

Comment: Isn't there an early scene in the movie where she sees the magic being done, and that's what makes her want Rapunzel('s hair)? I'm pretty sure I recall her watching someone else (the Queen maybe?) singing the song before she even kidnaps Rapunzel, but it's been a while since I last watched this one...

Comment: @Kromey no, you're thinking of someone singing to the flower before it's used to heal Rapunzel.  And that person is mother Gothel...so how did she know what to sing to the flower.

Comment: She's a witch. Witches know things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The official '[Tangled Junior Novel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0736426795)' (issued by Disney Press) specifically recounts how Mother Gothel learned the "[Healing Incantation](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Incantation)":

> One day, an old woman named Mother Gothel was singing softly to herself during one of her walks along a craggy hillside. She looked down and discovered the Golden Flower.
>
> **Just as she was about to pluck the flower from the ground, she noticed that it was glowing. As she kept singing, Mother Gothel's brittle voice become strong and clear. Her old bones didn't seem to ache any more.** She looked at her shrivelled hand and saw that all her wrinkles were gone. suddenly, she was young again, and her eyes widened with selfish delight!
>
> Right then and there, Mother Gothel decided to leave the flower where it was, so that she could continue to use its power. It was a secret she kept all to herself. For centuries, she lived contentedly, singing to the flower each day, making it glow with the magic that kept her young and beautiful. And because of her covetous protection of the flower, no one else benefited from the blossom's healing gifts.

It seems that it's the *singing* that's important rather than the actual words, something that's borne out by the fact that the power can be released either by brewing the flower or crying out some magic tears.

[image]